# Joomla adds an empty space in some components

Tags: joomla, components, space, quotation-marks

I have a problem I've noticed a while ago with a site I'm building.

I've been working with Joomla for a while now and I have never encountered such a problem.

On some components, like featured content, search, hwdvideoshare and some more, quotation marks seem to be added at the very top of the main content area. This causes an extra empty space that pushes the content down.

It's not really acceptable since I am designing a layout that has to be very precise.

[image: Here's a little demonstration]

Hopefully you guys can help me, I have tried everything.

Comment: It might be something with UTF with BOM.. What is the encoding on your template? Also, can you show us the code that includes the component?

Comment: I've tried setting UTF without BOM for the template, but that didn't help. When I look at the source in Chrome, it still shows UTF8 with BOM. This is what includes the component <jdoc:include type="component" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the "index.php" file in the template with notepad++. Then from encoding choose "Convert to UTF8 without BOM", save and reload.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was UTF8 with BOM.
However, it wasn't on the template file.
I started looking for what's in common in all the sites that added the empty space.
It was pagination. Converted the pagination file to UTF8 without BOM and works flawlessly now.